# Why is code that runs successfully in Console returning `Error: Incomplete Expression` in Rmarkdown chunk?

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, data-visualization, scatter-plot

```r
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(Data, x=~x1, y=~x2, z=~x3, color=~y, colors=c("darkblue","darkred")) %>%
     add_markers(size=1)
fig
```

I have a table with variables `y`, `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`. `y` is a binary factor, and the others are scalars. When I wrote the code above in a **.rmd file** and ran the chunk, it returns `Error: Incomplete expression:` , although the plot is successfully generated if I just run the same code in the **Console**. How could this happen?

Comment: Is your object `Data` also created/available in the RMD file or just in your R environment?

Comment: @J_F Yes, it's a simulated dataset so available in both environments.

Comment: Can you give us your RMD file and part of the data set?